# Linux: not able to see all options for `tree` command

Tags: linux, command-line, tree

I'm trying to list the contents of a directory recursively and in color using the `tree -C` command.  However, my shell reports an error and it displays an info-entry for `sed` instead.  The `tree` command by itself works fine but it seems that a number of the options (e.g., `tree -a`) are not available to me.

I've tried installing a new version using `sudo apt-get install tree` but no luck.  I'm experiencing this behavior in both `bash` and `zsh` (LXDE/Ubuntu 14.04).

Any suggestions that would allow me to use `tree` with the full set of options (listed here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)?

```
~ tree -C                                                                 ⏎
sed: invalid option -- 'C'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  -e script, --expression=script
                 add the script to the commands to be executed
  -f script-file, --file=script-file
                 add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
  --follow-symlinks
                 follow symlinks when processing in place
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
  -l N, --line-length=N
                 specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
  --posix
                 disable all GNU extensions.
  -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script.
  -s, --separate
                 consider files as separate rather than as a single continuous
                 long stream.
  -u, --unbuffered
                 load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
                 the output buffers more often
  -z, --null-data
                 separate lines by NUL characters
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file option is given, then the first
non-option argument is taken as the sed script to interpret.  All
remaining arguments are names of input files; if no input files are
specified, then the standard input is read.

GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so I'll put this here.

It almost looks like the `tree` command is aliased to `sed` on your machine.  When I run `tree -C` on my machine, I get the expected behavior.  When I run `sed -C` on my computer, I get the exact same output that you get when you run `tree -C`.

Is there any entry in your `~/.bashrc` file that defines an alias like that?

Comment: bingo.  i'd added some predefined aliases a while ago that i'd forgotten about, including one for `tree`.  at the time, i didn't know about the `tree` package for Ubunutu...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tree command as:

```
tree /boot/
tree -d /boot/
tree -C /boot/
```

Comment: Without further explanation this is more of a comment than an answer.